# face box pop up issue with IE6,7,8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, facebox, continuous-integration

I am using **CI**.
I am loading one view page in popup.
when this view is modified.
It's not showing the correct latest updated content in pop up. but it shows the content that is loaded at the first time when pop up is opened.
Please help.

Comment: please provide more information. Such as some of the code that might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to the "Stack Trace Overflow" error in Ie7. I've fixed it by calling all scripts first and dependencies before calling the facebox.js last.

Answer (score 0):

its because when we click on any button or link and open this pop-up at that time page is not getting refreshed but its only open the hidden div.so its obviously come up with the previous data.you have to refresh this page after submitting.

Try this, may work.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. In FF and chrome it is working fine.
IE is having problem. 

Page refresh also didn't work. But If I close browser. and reopens then it shows required data.

and our requirement is no  page refresh.
Pop up opens new page on click of link. It's not in div of same page.